# How can I prove that the following functions are even?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f_{1}$ & $f_{2}$ are both even on A. $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove that the next functions are even:

(i) $\lambda f_{1}(x) + \mu f_{2}(x).$

(ii) $f_{1}(x) f_{2}(x).$

I see that they are so trivial questions, for example, my answer to the first question is:

$\lambda f_{1}(-x) + \mu f_{2}(-x) =  \lambda f_{1}(x) + \mu f_{2}(x).$ (as   $f_{1}$ & $f_{2}$ are even functions)

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's instant.

Comment: You are right, as long as you observe that the left and right hand side of your expression are $(\lambda f_1 + \mu f_2)(-x)$ and $(\lambda f_1 + \mu f_2)(x)$ respectively (also trivial, but worth a mention, I thought).

Comment: Certainly worth a mention @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг